# trying to align simple_form box and button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I'm using the simple_form gem in my rails app. When testing the app, everything looks fine on my pc, but on others, sometimes I can't see the button - it seems to be hidden behind the input box.

How can I have it so the button will be aligned just to the right of the input box? Right now I've hard coded the position, which works good on my pc, but not on all others, as I said.

I thought 'float:right;' would do it, as the input box and button are in a parent div, but it sends it all the way to the right of the screen. I also toyed around with 'clear:both', with no success. Thanks for any help.

Here's my code:

```
          <div id ='search-box'>

  <%= simple_form_for @review, :url => search_index_path, :method => :post, :html => {} do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :search_ids, :collection => @data, :as => :grouped_chosen, 
                :group_method => :last, :prompt => false,
                :input_html => { :class => 'span5', :multiple => true }, 
                #:label => t('find_something.search_label'), 
                :placeholder => t('find_something.search_placeholder') %>

    <%= f.button :submit, :value => t('find_something.button_text'), :class => 'btn-primary search-button'%>

  <% end %>

</div>
```

And my css:

```
  #search-box {

      .controls {
        width:50px;
        margin-left: 390px;
        margin-top: 18px;

        .control-group.grouped_chosen {
          float: left;
          display: inline;
          width: 540px;

        }
      }

      .search-button {
        float: right;
        margin-right: 473px;
        margin-top: -43px;
      }

      }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, dsiplaying input box and button on the same line. I found the tip on a previous question from stackoverflow.com.

In the simple_form_for line I changed:

```
:html => {} do |f|
```

to

```
:html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f|
```

So it looked like:

```
  <%= simple_form_for @review, :url => search_index_path, :method => :post, :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f| %>

    <%= f.input :search_ids, :collection => @data, :as => :grouped_chosen, 
                :group_method => :last, :prompt => false,
                :input_html => { :class => 'span5', :multiple => true }, 
                :label => false, 
                :placeholder => t('find_something.search_placeholder') %>

    <%= f.button :submit, :value => t('find_something.button_text'), :class => 'btn-primary search-button'%>

  <% end %>



</div>
```

And in my css I put:

```
.form-inline div { 
display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your output HTML? By default, these fields will align correctly, so you don't need all the floats and margins.

http://jsfiddle.net/gpnZS/

```
    <div id="search-box">
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="search-control" value="Search me"/>
        <button class="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

If you need more than this, check out the display: inline-block property.

Comment: Hi Rob R, thanks for the tip. What do you mean by 'Output HTML'? Played around with 'inline-block property', display inline and lots of other things for hours and hours, with no luck. Got it sorted eventually though - see my answer below.

Comment: By output HTML, I mean what is rendered in the browser. what you have posted is ruby, which will parse and deliver output HTML into the browser.